# Intellij: "Could not autowire. There is more than one bean of 'MyType' type" With @ConditionalOnProperty

Tags: intellij-idea

In my spring boot app IntelliJ shows me the warning `Could not autowire. There is more than one bean of 'MyType' type.`

In fact there are two beans but they are defined with condition on property

```java
@Service
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "features.feature1", havingValue = "true")
public class Bean1 implements SomeInterface{

}
```

And the second one depends on the same property in `application.yml` but if it is set to `false`

```java
@Service
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "features.feature1", havingValue = "false", matchIfMissing = true)
public class Bean2 implements SomeInterface{

}
```

Is there a way to make IntelliJ understand this and don't show the warning? Project runs without problems.

Comment: Make sure the Spring Context is configured for module https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spring-support.html#configure-spring-project-facet. make sure to try the version from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download  If application runs correctly but issue still remains file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with a sample project.

Comment: @Vitalii, hello! Did you solve this question? I'm in the same situation right now, searching for an answer...

Comment: No, I just ignore it

Comment: I had a similar problem, and I think ignoring is fine in this case. You can do that with adding this annotation: @SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaInjectionPointsAutowiringInspection") SomeInterface someInterface

Answer (score 0):

For me it was easier and cleaner to just create a class combining these Conditionals so that I could use this with `@ConditionalOnBean` for example

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "features.feature1", havingValue = "false", matchIfMissing = true)
    public class FeatureIsFalse{
}
```

Then you can use

```
@Service
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(FeatureIsFalse.class)
public class Bean1 implements SomeInterface{

}
```

and

```
@Service
@ConditionalOnBean(FeatureIsFalse.class)
public class Bean2 implements SomeInterface{

}
```

Let me know if this worked for you.